# How to have line width in IntelliJ automatically adjust when screen width is changed?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm switching over to IntelliJ from Sublime Text Editor and in IntelliJ, when I either shrink the width of the IDE or split the screen into two editors, my code goes off the screen and I have to manually scroll left/right to see it all.  How can I change the settings so it is like Sublime where the line lengths will automatically adjust to the width of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences > Editor > General > Use soft wraps in editor
[image]